# Iso Cluster Unsupervised Classification error 000814 Invalid File Type in ModelBuilder of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arccatalog, error-000814

When trying to run the Iso Cluster Unsupervised Classification tool in ModelBuilder my model always fails at this step due to an invalid file type.
However, when I pull this process out and place it in a stand alone model everything works fine.

Has anyone experienced this problem before?

[image: Stand Alone Model]

[image: Larger Model]

Comment: Its not clear what you are showing? You seem to be showing us 2 models, what do you mean by "when I pull this process out", are one of these models you are showing what you are referring to as a stand alone model? Edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: The first screenshot is copied directly from the larger model below. When running the larger model the iso cluster tool fails to recognize the raster. However, when I copy and paste the exact process and place it in a new model the tool runs fine.

Comment: May be stick a make raster layer tool between clip and the iso tool as in your first model image?